# Change the page where backend users are redirected after login

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

By default the user is redirected to the dashboard.
How can I change that so that the user is redirected to my plugins page?

Answer (score 6):

Backend controllers fire the `backend.page.beforeDisplay` event which we can listen to in our plugins `boot()` method and then redirect the user:

```
// listen for the display event of the Dashboard controller
Event::listen('backend.page.beforeDisplay', function($controller, $action){
    // redirect from dashboard to somewhere else
    if ($action == 'index' && $controller instanceof \Backend\Controllers\Index){
        return Backend::redirect('acme/plugin/somewhere');
    }
});
```

Additional conditions can of course be added.

Answer (score -1):

The first and easy approach is to remove the "View desktop" permission to that user or create a group without that permission.

Second.

You can hook the appropriated event on your plugin's `boot` method and make the redirect.

```php
Event::listen('backend.user.login',function($user){
     return Backend::redirect('acme/yourplugin/controller/method');
});
```

PS. don't forget to set the `$elevated=true` on your plugin according to documentation [October Docs - elevated permissions](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration#elevated-plugin)

Comment: When you remove the permission to view the dashboard, then the user is redirected to the next viewable page. You cannot specify which one

Comment: You can, by defining the priority when registering pages in plugin.php.

Comment: Did you test the redirect? The event is fired in the user model `afterLogin()` function and the return value is not processed. Therefore returning the redirect does nothing